# Is there a SIP client that supports RTP/SAVPF?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, webrtc

I want to know if there's a SIP Client Application (preferably for Linux) that supports SAVPF so I can make it interoperable with WebRTC ?

Comment: A client application or a client library?

Comment: A client Application, preferably for Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the Doubango SIP clients.

They use it in their HTML5 SIP client.

http://doubango.org

EDIT: They also provide a webrtc2sip gateway that, when installed, makes it possible to use any other SIP client and call to a webrtc client.